# after Intent.ACTION_CALL, how to know if the call is not picked up

Tags: android, telephony

I am developing an app, where I need to know if no one picked up the call when I call using

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:4654545"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

if not picked up, I want to open up a popup asking user if he wants to dial next number in that contact.

How to find out if the previous call was not picked up??

`PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` gives me only 3 states
`EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`
`EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`
`CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`

Comment: nop :( Could not find any solution for this.